# ¿Como puedo dividir una cadena?

Tags: php, fpdf

Me pueden ayudar,estoy realizando la creacion de un horario, trabajo con php usando fpdf, de una cadena que hace consulta a la base de datos, estoy extrayendo nombres de personas con apellidos, pero estos pueden variar, nombre+apellido1, nombre+apellido2, etc. necesito separar los nombres para poderlos en forma de lista de acuerdo a la materia, algunas materias tienen mas de 1 profesor y es con estos con los que estoy teniendo problema.

Utilice explode, pero las materias con mas de 1 profesor no me las muestra, mi codigo es un poco largo por lo que pongo el fragmento de donde estoy tomando el codigo para la impresion de la informacion.

```
<?php

$cadena2="Select distinct cve_mat,asignatura,grupo_ord,lunes,martes,miercoles,jueves,viernes,sabado,cve_int,
                            grupo_ext,aula,profesor,'00','00',clave_tal,nota2,nota1,aula1, cve_mata, cve_inta, semestrea, aasignatur
                    from hor".$qsemac." h
                    where (cve_mat=".$qcve." or cve_mata=".$qcve." or cve_inta=".$qcve." )
                                and (grupo_ord='".$qgpo."' or grupo_ext='".$qgpo."')
                            and (cve_mat=cve_int or nota2='/' or nota2='*' or cve_mat>6000)
                    order by cve_mat,nota2,nota1";  //fin de la cadena

$qresul2=pg_query($db,$cadena2);



$profe=fnReemplazarHTML(trim($r2[12]));

$DividirProfe= explode(" ", $profe);
        $profe1= $DividirProfe[0];
        $profe2= $DividirProfe[1];
        $profe3= $DividirProfe[2];

$pdf->SetXY(31.5,$linea);
        $pdf->SetFont('helvetica','B',8);
        $pdf->Cell(82,4,utf8_decode($qnoma),0,2,'L'); // MATERIA
        $pdf->SetFont('helvetica','B',7.5);
        $pdf->Cell(82,3,utf8_decode('Profesor: '.$profe1.$profe2.$profe3),0,'L');   //PROFESOR




?>
```

[image: Marco con rojo los saltos de linea que necesito]

Comment: La cadena asi se encuentra guardada en la bd?

Comment: Acabo de hacer la division de los profes colocando una diagonal, me podrias ayudar a saber como separlos por medio de esta y que me quedaran en forma de lista, esto es como estoy formulando la impresion de los profes -->        while ($r2=pg_fetch_array($qresul2))
      {
          if ($profe<>trim($r2[12])) $profe.='/'.trim($r2[12]);
//$profe.='/ '.trim($r2[12]);
        
             
            
      }

Comment: Puedes usar `explode` y para trabajar con ellos un `foreach`

Comment: Muchas Gracias, lo voy a intentar.

Comment: A mí me parece que en tu BBDD los cursos con varios profesores los traen separados por comas

Comment: Creo que es mejor resolver esto a nivel de la consulta SQL, armándola de tal modo que traigas los datos listos para consumir. Eso lo puedes lograr por ejemplo con `CONCAT`

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios, todos me sirvieron y al final termine arreglandolo desde base de datos.